# What am I doing wrong? cannot compile

Tags: solidity, compilation

Hi for some reason i keep getting this error, while trying to compile, im using a code I found in forums, but i seem not to be able to understand why it doesnt compile, what am I missing?.
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That simply is not Solidity. It looks more like Viper to me, the Pythonic brother of Solidity.